# Add new column based on values of another column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like these

| Name | Position |
| --- | --- |
| Simon | Chef |
| David | Assistant Chef |
| Philipp | Collegial Chef |
| Rafael | Assistant Chef |
| Gregory | Collegial Chef |
| Dani | Assistant Fellow |
| Diego | Collegial Fellow |
| Patrick | Assistant Fellow |
| Robert | Collegial Fellow |
| Glen | Chef |
| Michael | Assistant Chef |
| William | Collegial Chef |
| Carter | Assistant Chef |
| Anthony | Collegial Chef |
| Timothy | Assistant Fellow |
| Jeremy | Collegial Fellow |
| Brian | Assistant Fellow |
| Ceasar | Collegial Fellow |

Now I would like to add an additional column based on the values of the Position column.

I would like to create a column called role and this column has only 3 values (Chef, Assistant and Collegial)

Everything in the position who is only chef will have in the role the name one.
Everything in the position who is something with collegial will have in the role the name  collegial.
Everything in the position who is something with assistant will have in the role the name  assistant.

I am expecting these output

| Name | Position | Role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Simon | Chef | One |
| David | Assistant Chef | Assistant |
| Philipp | Collegial Chef | Collegial |
| Rafael | Assistant Chef | Assistant |
| Gregory | Collegial Chef | Collegial |
| Dani | Assistant Fellow | Assistant |
| Diego | Collegial Fellow | Collegial |
| Patrick | Assistant Fellow | Assistant |
| Robert | Collegial Fellow | Collegial |
| Glen | Chef | One |
| Michael | Assistant Chef | Assistant |
| William | Collegial Chef | Collegial |
| Carter | Assistant Chef | Assistant |
| Anthony | Collegial Chef | Collegial |
| Timothy | Assistant Fellow | Assistant |
| Jeremy | Collegial Fellow | Collegial |
| Brian | Assistant Fellow | Assistant |
| Ceasar | Collegial Fellow | Collegial |

I don't know how to code it? Could someone please help. The problem is some names in the column have also chef.

```
df['Role'] = np.where(df['Position'] == ["Chef"], 'Chef', 'Non Chef')
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I code it, but could not find the solution

Comment: I add  the code, but this is wrong

Comment: Show your coding attempt and tell us what specific problem you are encountering

Comment: I only know how to code, if there are only two possible values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand` parameter set to `True`. Select the first column from the result and chain [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to replace "Chef" with "One".

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': {0: 'Simon', 1: 'David', 2: 'Philipp', 3: 'Rafael', 
                 4: 'Gregory', 5: 'Dani', 6: 'Diego', 7: 'Patrick', 
                 8: 'Robert', 9: 'Glen', 10: 'Michael', 11: 'William', 
                 12: 'Carter', 13: 'Anthony', 14: 'Timothy', 15: 'Jeremy', 
                 16: 'Brian', 17: 'Ceasar'}, 
        'Position': {0: 'Chef', 1: 'Assistant Chef', 2: 'Collegial Chef', 
                     3: 'Assistant Chef', 4: 'Collegial Chef', 
                     5: 'Assistant Fellow', 6: 'Collegial Fellow', 
                     7: 'Assistant Fellow', 8: 'Collegial Fellow', 
                     9: 'Chef', 10: 'Assistant Chef', 11: 'Collegial Chef', 
                     12: 'Assistant Chef', 13: 'Collegial Chef', 
                     14: 'Assistant Fellow', 15: 'Collegial Fellow', 
                     16: 'Assistant Fellow', 17: 'Collegial Fellow'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Role'] = df.Position.str.split(' ', expand=True)[0].replace('Chef','One')

print(df)

       Name          Position       Role
0     Simon              Chef        One
1     David    Assistant Chef  Assistant
2   Philipp    Collegial Chef  Collegial
3    Rafael    Assistant Chef  Assistant
4   Gregory    Collegial Chef  Collegial
5      Dani  Assistant Fellow  Assistant
6     Diego  Collegial Fellow  Collegial
7   Patrick  Assistant Fellow  Assistant
8    Robert  Collegial Fellow  Collegial
9      Glen              Chef        One
10  Michael    Assistant Chef  Assistant
11  William    Collegial Chef  Collegial
12   Carter    Assistant Chef  Assistant
13  Anthony    Collegial Chef  Collegial
14  Timothy  Assistant Fellow  Assistant
15   Jeremy  Collegial Fellow  Collegial
16    Brian  Assistant Fellow  Assistant
17   Ceasar  Collegial Fellow  Collegial
```

**Option 2**

Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex pattern, and chain [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with 'One'.

```
df['Role'] = df.Position.str.extract(r'(.*)(?=\s\w+$)').fillna('One')
# capturing everything followed by a whitespace + any word char until end of string
print(df)
# same result
```